# replacing the dot symbol in the array

Tags: javascript

In the first line, the input is the line d. In the second line, a series of words separated by a dot is entered. You need to output these words by separating each word with a combination of d characters.

example:

Sample Input: d= /|
dej.fow.orj.jkk.fgo.pwk.pkp.lde.efe
Sample Output:
dej/|\fow/|\orj/|\jkk/|\fgo/|\pwk/|\pkp/|\lde/|\efe

```
    let d=prompt();
    let b=prompt();
    let arr=b.split('');
    for(let i in arr) {
        if(i.indexOf('.') !== -1){
            arr = i.replace(i.indexOf('.'), d)
      }
    }
    arr = arr.join()
    console.log(arr)`
```

It doesn't work!

Comment: `for...in` loops using the index, not the value, you are probably looking for `for...of`, and then you might want to use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`, which only replaces the first instance if the given selector is not a global regex. After that, you probably don't want to _assign_ to `arr` as the end result is no longer an array, you might want `arr[i]`, but in that case you should use `for...in` and `arr[i]` instead of `i`.

Comment: It should be like this ```arr.toString().replaceAll('.','/|\')```

Comment: @Newbee You mean `b.replaceAll(...)`. `arr.toString()` concatenates the items of `arr` with comma.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the special characters `\` (*escape*) and Regex's `.` (*any character*) using backslash: `\\` `\.`

```js
const d = "/|\\";
const input = "dej.fow.orj.jkk.fgo.pwk.pkp.lde.efe";
const result = input.replace(/\./g, d);
console.log(result)
```

- MDN: [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate characters with replacing the dot:

```js
const d = "/|\\";
const input = "dej.fow.orj.jkk.fgo.pwk.pkp.lde.efe";

let result = '';
const arr = input.split('');
for(let i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
  result += arr[i] === '.' ?  '/|\\' : arr[i];
}

console.log(result);
```

`Array::reduce()` version:

```js
const d = "/|\\";
const input = "dej.fow.orj.jkk.fgo.pwk.pkp.lde.efe";

const result = input.split('').reduce((r, c) => r += c === '.' ?  '/|\\' : c, '');

console.log(result);
```

A benchmark:

```
` Chrome/121
-----------------------------------------------
Alexander  1.00x | x1000000 139 139 146 150 152
Roco       1.17x | x1000000 163 165 165 168 216
-----------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
// @benchmark Roco
'dej.fow.orj.jkk.fgo.pwk.pkp.lde.efe'.replace(/\./g, '/|\\')

// @benchmark Alexander
let output = '';
const arr = 'dej.fow.orj.jkk.fgo.pwk.pkp.lde.efe'.split('');
for(let i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
  output += arr[i] === '.' ?  '/|\\' : arr[i];
}
output;

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="demo"> Mr . has a blue house and a . car.</p>


let str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
let res = str.replace(/./g, "d");
```

OutPut:
Mr d has a blue house and a d car.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're trying to replace the dots in the input string b with the character d. However, there are a few issues in your code. You can achieve this by using the split and join methods correctly. Here's the corrected code:

```
let d = prompt();
let b = prompt();
let arr = b.split('.'); // Split the input string by dots

// Join the array elements with the character 'd'
let result = arr.join(d);

console.log(result);
```

With this code, it will correctly split the input string b by dots and then join the elements with the character d, giving you the desired output.